# ggplot labels on dodged barplot are uneven

Tags: r, ggplot2

Building on the solution provided to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017460/position-geom-text-on-dodged-barplot). Does anyone know why the labels on the plot are off center? As you can see in the image below, the labels on the pink bar are slightly lower vertically than on the teal bar. Is there anyway to correct this?

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
dtf <- structure(list(variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("vma", "vla", "ia", "fma", "fla"), class = "factor"), 
    ustanova = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L), .Label = c("srednja škola", "fakultet"), class = "factor"), 
    `(all)` = c(42.9542857142857, 38.7803203661327, 37.8996138996139, 
    33.7672811059908, 29.591439688716, 26.1890660592255, 27.9557692307692, 
    23.9426605504587, 33.2200772200772, 26.9493087557604)), .Names = c("variable", 
"ustanova", "(all)"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = c("cast_df", 
"data.frame"), idvars = c("variable", "ustanova"), rdimnames = list(
    structure(list(variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("vma", "vla", "ia", "fma", 
    "fla"), class = "factor"), ustanova = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("srednja škola", 
    "fakultet"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("variable", "ustanova"
    ), row.names = c("vma_srednja škola", "vma_fakultet", "vla_srednja škola", 
    "vla_fakultet", "ia_srednja škola", "ia_fakultet", "fma_srednja škola", 
    "fma_fakultet", "fla_srednja škola", "fla_fakultet"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(value = structure(1L, .Label = "(all)", class = "factor")), .Names = "value", row.names = "(all)", class = "data.frame")))

ggplot(bar) + 
  geom_bar(aes(variable, `(all)`, fill = ustanova), position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(variable, `(all)`, label = sprintf("%2.1f", `(all)`)), 
            position = position_dodge(width = 1)) + 
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: Try with `width=.9` which is the default width of the bars.

Comment: That did it. Thanks very much. If you provide solution in full answer happy to give green check!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the width argument in position\_dodge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889766/what-is-the-width-argument-in-position-dodge) Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50847404/5325862)